# PHP is not able to connect to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp

I am a very new to website development, I am using XAMPP on OSX. Both the Apache and MySQL servers are running. However, my PHP code is not able to connect to the database. Im using these credentials, and the right password:

```
$host= "localhost"
$user= "root";
$password = "";
$database = "";

$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die("Query died: connect");
```

error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'died' (T_STRING) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/web/login_reg.php on line 7

Error line : include("dbstuff.inc");
```

Comment: The first quote in the die doesn't look right. Try : `die("Query died: connect");`

Comment: you are using wrong quote ! include('dbstuff.inc');

Comment: When you installed your database, did you create a password or are you using the default password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is at `or die("Query died: connect");`

Try this instead:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
```

---

```
mysqli_connect
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: Hi, sorry for the trouble this is my first post I am just starting student. but guess what the error was---> " ” the difference in this two double quotes.I copied the login script from a book. that's why error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the style your using then use this, "name" should be the database name you've created.

```
<?php
$dbConnect = array(
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => '',
    'name' => ''
);
$db = new mysqli(
    $dbConnect['server'],
    $dbConnect['user'],
    $dbConnect['pass'],
    $dbConnect['name']
);
if ($db->connect_errno>0) {
    echo "Database connection error" . $db->connect_error;
    exit;
}
?>
```